# wxPython - UltimateListCtrl.ScreenToClient Type Error

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I cannot seem to call UltimateListCtrl.ScreenToClient(pos). I keep getting a type error. I enter a tuple of (x,y) and I get

```
TypeError: ScreenToClient() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I enter x, y individually and I get

```
TypeError: Window_ScreenToClient() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Any help? Is this a problem with UltimateListControl? Is there an easy work around? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a problem in the UltimateListCtrl.

Fortunately there is a fairly straightforward fix.  Find the `ultimatelistctrl.py` file that the UltimateListCtrl is loaded from, find the `ScreenToClient` method within this and replace the line

```
        return self._mainWin.ScreenToClient(x, y)
```

with

```
        return self._mainWin.ScreenToClient((x, y))
```

The full path of the `ultimatelistctrl.py` file should be in the exception traceback when you specify `x` and `y` individually.  On my machine it's `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.9.3-msw\wx\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py`.  The traceback also mentions the line number of the line in this method, in my case 12457.

I'd recommend making the same change to the `ClientToScreen` method in the `ultimatelistctrl.py` file, as it has the same problem.

Comment: If the solution is that simple, why hasn't the change been pushed through? Also, what is the best way to make that change, but still have a program to be portable from one machine to another without modifying the wx package?

Comment: @Shatners: you can try using the `ScreenToClientXY` (and `ClientToScreenXY`) methods, which I wasn't previously aware of until I came across [this issue on the wxWidgets bug tracker](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13938).  Alternatively you can create a subclass of UltimateListCtrl and override the methods.